# Not loading Css and Js files after upgrading to SItecore 9

Tags: javascript, css, sitecore, sitecore9

We have upgraded our Sitecore from 7 to 9. Not loading the Css and Js files

Comment: Do you use bundling? What is the response of the css / js request? 404? 500?

Comment: Yes we do. Its the 404 error

Comment: Try adding `/bundles` or whatever is your css and js path to `ignoredUrlPrefixes` setting

Comment: Thanks Marek. As I am new to sitecore, can you help me where i can put that piece of line?

Comment: http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-patchable-ignore-lists/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I did the same thing as the Mark mentioned in the linnk. But still its not loading the css and js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a patch file to have Sitecore ignore the url you're using in your bundle. Without that, Sitecore will try to serve something up itself. Here is an example of the patch file you need (you can strip out the rest):

https://www.sitecorefundamentals.com/using-sitecore-to-manage-your-bundled-assets